# Yii2 MVC base Authorization

Tags: yii2, authorization, rbac

I have a trouble with my yii2 project. I used RBAC Authorization and it worked properly.

In this code below, **`'@'`** mean user who signed in. It is in **`SiteController`** - which not use RBAC.

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'confirm', 'changepassword', 'thongbao', 'request-password-reset', 'reset-password', 'distance',
                        'nhatram', 'updatediaban', 'leas', 'thongkell', 'thongkells', 'nodetb', 'xemnode', 'bcthang','mailcb'
                    ],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'leaslineall', 'up'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

So I want to authorize some action for only specific user named **`"Superadmin"`**

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: who downvoted without comment? pls tell me the reason! dont be a kid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this reference?

It is about your RBAC authorization very detailed

https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user

Comment: You should and some explanation and not onli a link.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva sorry, Im a new comer, sorry